# Ubuntu unable to detect Huawei E392 USB modem with Airtel 4G connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, usb-modem, huawei, 4g

Ubuntu unable to detect Huawei E392 USB modem with Airtel 4G connection.

[image]

**Output of `lsusb`**

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0461:4d15 Primax Electronics, Ltd Dell Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04b3:3025 IBM Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 12d1:1505 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E398 LTE/UMTS/GSM Modem/Networkcard
```

**Output of `dmesg`**

```
[  331.084423] usb 3-7: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  331.103177] usb 3-7: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
[  331.103184] usb 3-7: ep 0x1 - rounding interval to 32768 microframes, ep desc says 0 microframes
[  331.109954] scsi8 : usb-storage 3-7:1.0
[  332.109577] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[  332.157291] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy
[  332.157626] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[  332.157852] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
[  332.291031] scsi 8:0:0:0: killing request
```

Can someone please help me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal

```
sudo -H gedit /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules
```

and add a line to the file

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1505", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
```

Then run

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/12d1:1505
```

And paste this text to the editor

```
 TargetVendor= 0x12d1
 TargetProduct= 0x1505
 MessageContent="55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000"
```

Save the file.

Unplug the modem and plug it in again. In about 20 seconds try to create a connection.

Comment: How did you come up with the message content?

Comment: sudo tee  -a /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules <<< " ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1505", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"
is this command right coz its not doing anything....

Comment: It is still not showing anything on my network manager

Comment: It does. It adds a line to file `lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules`. Do not run it many times. Check if you added two or more lines there.

Comment: Maybe reboot is needed.

Comment: sudo tee  -a /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules <<< " ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1505", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'"


> 
See it goes to this promt

Comment: Oops, sry. I will correct it.